# Synthetic event doesnt work as expected in function component

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, synthetic

I have 2 examples, one with class component and one with function component doing exactly the same thing. Im using react 16.13.1. I know that if you dont persist the event you will get an error saying that the event target is null. This happens as expected in class component. In function component though, this isnt the case. What is the difference between them?

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { text: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState(() => ({
      text: event.target.value
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Text: </span>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ text: "" });
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setState({
      text: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Text: </span>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={state.text} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all comes down to the timing for when `this.setState()` and `setState()` is called. In your class component, the additional arrow function declaration inside `this.setState` causes an additional delay that makes the call take longer than the `useState` hook in the functional component. If you wrap the `setState()` call in your functional component with a `setTimeout` of `100`, you get an error as expected. Also, if you modify the `setState` call to `this.setState({ text: event.target.value })` in your class-based component, you no longer get an error. Finally figured that out with some inspiration from the official [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html).

Comment: Indeed it works as you. But inside the setTimeout: 
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(event.target.value); // Works
    }, 1000);  console prints an empty value. Shouldnt be what i wrote in the input?

Comment: That is because your input is a controlled component, and if you are not updating your state in `handleChange`, then your input value will reset to the initial state `""`, and that is being logged.